# Fetching and evaluating data from several dictionaries using filter,reduce,add,map

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

**Fetching and evaluating data from several dictionaries using filter,reduce,add,map**
I would like to calculate the following:

1. Filter each category, take the values of the keys (t1,t2,t3..)
2. take out the values of 'a','b'.
3. add from Addons to each value in the same category
4. multiply each one

   result = ((80+5)*2.5 + (95+5)*4 + (75+3)*3.5 + (58+10)*5)

The Data to work with:

```
Values = {'b': 95, 'c': 75, 'a': 80, 'd': 58}
Multipliers = {'b': 4, 'c': 3.5, 'a': 2.5, 'd': 5}
Addons = {'t1':5, 't2':3, 't3':10} 
Category = {'t1':('a', 'b'), 't2':('c',), 't3':('d',)}
```

what I did so far is to filter each category that correspond to Addons,now I`m just able to print it:

```
reduce(add,map(lambda x,y: x[1],filter(lambda t: t[0] in Addons, Category.items())))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Just as a quick comment... Just because you *can* do everything on one line, it doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: My answer shows how to do it your way, but it's much more complicated than the other method proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum((Values[v] + Addons[c]) * Multipliers[v] 
         for c, vs in Category.items() 
              for v in vs if c in Addons)
# 1225.5
```

Comment: there is option to use filter in this situation?

Comment: @OfirAttia I don't completely get how do you want to filter, neither from text, nor from test case, can you clarify what should be filtered off

Comment: Good answer, which is why I +1, but what `filter` does in this case is return the tuples such that the keys in `Category` are also in `Addons`.  So, this would crash if that is not true.  I would go with your answer as it's simple, but check out mine if you want to see a working implementation with his logic.

Comment: @SteveP. It's easy to add an `if` statement in this sum, but I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
reduce(add,map(lambda x,y: x[1],filter(lambda t: t[0] in Addons, Category.items())))
```

`Category.items()` returns `(key, value)` pairs as tuples.
`filter(lambda t: t[0] in Addons, Category.items())` will return all tuples whose keys are also keys in `Addons`

Yet in `map()` your `lamda` function takes two arguments, but your are only giving tuples, so that should be `map(lambda x: x[1]...)`, which will return all of the `values` from `Category` whose keys are also in `Addons`

Next, `reduce` will add all of the keys together. Here's a correct implementation for doing it your way, but **I would go with the accepted answer**, as it's intuitive and simple:

```
reduce(add, 
       reduce(add, 
       map(lambda x: [Multipliers[val]*(Values[val] + Addons[x[0]]) for val in x[1]],
       filter(lambda x: x[0] in Addons, Category.items()))))
```

The **only exception** is if all of the keys in `Categories` are **not** in `Addons`, then the accepted answer will <strike>not work</strike> (I edited his answer with the fix), but this will.

Answer (score 0):

1. it's not a good practice to capitalize vars, it's recommended to use [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)
2. I think you should solve it simple, and not in 1 line.

Here is my simple solution:

```
values = {'b': 95, 'c': 75, 'a': 80, 'd': 58}
multipliers = {'b': 4, 'c': 3.5, 'a': 2.5, 'd': 5}
addons = {'t1':5, 't2':3, 't3':10}
category = {'t1':('a', 'b'), 't2':('c',), 't3':('d',)}

outputString = ""

for value in category:
    for item in list(category[value]):
        if value in addons and item in values and item in multipliers:
            addonStr = "({} + {})*{}".format(values[item], addons[value], multipliers[item])
            outputString += addonStr

outputString = "(" + outputString + ")"

print outputString
```

Output:

```
((75 + 3)*3.5(58 + 10)*5(80 + 5)*2.5(95 + 5)*4)
```

You can add and `else` statement so if you'll have error's in one of your dictionaries you'll be able to track it.